# Can I compare two properties of single kind in ndb of GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Can I compare two properties of single kind in ndb of GAE?

```
class GameLog(ndb.Model):
    duration = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    time = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

I need compare these two properties. How can I do this?

```
GameLog.duration > GameLog.time
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this kind of thing you need to save the (precomputed) result, so it's indexed and you can query for it.

To make this easier ndb gives you [Computed Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed):

```
class GameLog(ndb.Model):
    duration = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    time = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    timeout = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.duration > self.time)
```

You don't need to maintain this property yourself, every time you `put()` the entity the value will get calculated and saved. Now you can do the query:

```
GameLog.query(GameLog.timeout == True)
```